# Time and Distance Puzzle: Equidistant Reunion of Cyclist and Car at the Intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, kinematics

A cyclist and a car, which is twice as fast as the cyclist, are approaching an intersection of two different streets perpendicular to each other. At noon they were at an equal distance from the intersection. Twenty minutes after noon the car was at the intersection. How many seconds from then on do they need to be equidistant from the intersection again?

Comment: Ivan, welcome to MSE. Pl. note that this forum requires that you must first edit in what efforts you have made, and where you are stuck to get necessary help

Comment: What did you try before to do?

Comment: When the car hits the intersection, the bicycle is clearly still 20 minutes away.  At this point, the car is pulling away from the intersection and the bike is continuing to approach the intersection.  Measure distance in terms of time.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).